# Unable to save Advanced Find query

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

One of my colleague's is not able to save an Advanced Find query. Options "Save" and "Save As" are grayed out. Searching the Internet revealed the solution. Access rights must be granted to entity 4230 (UserQuery). So I assigned all necessary rights to this entity.

I used a test account with the same rights as my colleague and used it to build the query, saved it. An error occurred saying that I have no CreateAccess rights. Which I have.

Am I missing something here.

Thanks for your help, 
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing it right but missing on some access privileges.  What you could test is to grant a super user rights to a new user (as in - the omnipotent rights to do everything). If you still don't get it to work, the issue isn't with access rights. If you do, you can go shotgun on it and turn on/off half of the grantees and see when you hit the brick wall.

Not nice but functional.   :)

Comment: My problem is that the logging is only mentioning ObjectTypeCode 4230. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Have you **tried** providing a total, complete access to everything and see if the error remains? If it doesn't, you can conclude that in your current setup, you do **not** provide sufficient access right (although it seems like you do). Until you've tested that approach, we can only be wild-guessing. Give it a try and let know how it went.